# do typing package need versions to be the same as package.json

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I was going through the [Angular quick start guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) when I noticed that

> "core-js": "^2.4.1",

in package.json is different from

> "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",

in the typings.js file.

Do these have to be the same or would the best practice be to remove version info from typings.js so that it always gets the latest typings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do these have to be the same

No. Use whatever version comes down. Its a snapshot of the *best known documentation* at that point in time. Then you can update later as needed.

> would the best practice be to remove version info from typings.js

Keep it for dependable builds.